# apex replayer debug in VS Code will not step through the class file even with the break points

Tags: apex-replay-debugger

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling and even that will not work. I set the breakpoint and get the debug log. Right mouse clicks in the log and selects the Apex Replayer Debug. It starts no problem but when I do the step through it does not step through the cls file. it seems to be stepping through the debug console. I've tested out a simple hello world class to test the most shallow call stack possible. Confirmed I'm executing the code in the correct Sandbox

Comment: Is the version of the code in your local sfdx project the same as the code in your target sandbox? Are your log levels appropriate (Apex = Finest, System = Fine, I think...whatever the max log level for those two categories are)? Have you tried closing all VSCode windows and then opening VSCode again (which does actually resolve problems from time to time)? How certain are you that you're actually executing the code that you've added breakpoints to? Is there a query, dml statement, or debug statement that you can use to find positive verification in your log that your target code is being run?

Comment: Have you turned on the apex replay debugger by executing the `SFDX: Turn On Apex Debug Log for Replay Debugger`?

Comment: yes, I've turned On Apex D Log. run the simple hello world in the dev console, loaded the debug log

Comment: I also went through the steps here to uninstall. https://superuser.com/questions/1380208/how-to-completely-uninstall-visual-studio-code-from-windows-10